# Functional equation with one given

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f(0)=−10$
and

$f(x)=(6x+4)^2−f(x+2)$
determine $f(3)$
I must be missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, the simple recursion formula determines $f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb 2Z$. One can choose $f(3)$ arbitrarily (and define $f(x)$ for odd integers $x$ via the recursion formula).

Comment: So it could be anything?

Comment: If you did not leave out anything important from the problem statement, then yes.

Comment: I dont recall leaving anything out only that f(x) is a polynomial

Comment: "only"!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: haha sorry about that

Comment: I thought you knew! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6671/discussion-between-fosho-and-hagen-von-eitzen)

Comment: anything? please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the additional constraint that $f$ is a polynomial, we can calculate $f(3)$.

Note that if $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots +a_1x+a_0$$
(with $a_n\ne 0$) is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $f(x+2)$ is also a polynomial of degree $n$ and has the same leading term, i.e. is of ther form
$$f(x+2)=a_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots +b_1 x+b_0.$$
Therefore $$36x^2+48x+16 = (6x+4)^2=f(x)+f(x+2)= 2a_nx^n+\ldots$$
implies that $n=2$ and $a_2=18$.
Thus $$f(x)=18x^2+bx+c.$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}36x^2+48x+16&=f(x)+f(x+2)\\
&=(18x^2+bx+c)+(18(x+2)^2+b(x+2)+c)\\
&=36x^2+(2b+72)x+(2b+2c+72)
\end{align},$$
which implies $2b+72=48$ and $2b+2c+72=16$, hence $b=-12$ and $c=-16$.
Thus
$$f(3)=36\cdot 9-12\cdot 3-16=110.$$

---

*Remark:* We did not use the given fact that $f(0)=-10$. In fact, we could determine $f$ without it and obtain $f(0)=-16$. Thus all in all the problem statement contradicts itself.